# How can I ensure that a function is "defined" in Python?

Tags: python, function

Trying to learn python as a java programmer. I would really appreciate some insight into why my program is telling me that my "isPrime" function isn't defined, especially with the use of 'self.'

```
import math

class Problem10:

    def sumOfPrimesX(self, number):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(0, number):
            if isPrime(i):
                sum += i
        return sum
    
    def isPrime(self, x):
        for n in range(0, math.floor(x/2)):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
        return True
        
    print(sumOfPrimesX(input()))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The reference should be ```self.isPrime()``` since it is a method of ```Problem10```  Ditto with ```sumOfPrimesX```

Comment: @ewong thank you! Am I otherwise using the 'self' keyword when appropriate? I understand that all functions need it as their first parameter in a python program.

Comment: yes, it seems like it.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword.

Comment: Also, my bad.  ```print(self.sumOfPrimesX(input()))``` is going to complain.

Comment: @ewong if I wanted to print some output using a function, would the best way to do it be print(Problem10.sumOfPrimesX(Problem10, x))? I'm thinking I'll move the x = input() command to the previous line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *all functions need it as their first parameter in a python program*

No, only the instance methods, the methods related to a specific instance of a class. A simple function can need to parameter.

And you won't see the parameter `self` filled with the classic way of calling it, if you call the method on a instance it'll be filled by it

```
p = Problem10()
p.sumOfPrimesX(int(input("Give a value")))  # call on instance, one paramater given

# same as 
Problem10.sumOfPrimesX(Problem10(), int(input("Give a value")))
# call on class itself, need to pass an instance as first to fill 'self
```

---

Also you need to wrap the `input` in an `int`, also start the loop at 2

```
p = Problem10()
print(p.sumOfPrimesX(int(input("Give a value"))))


class Problem10:

    def isPrime(self, x):
        for n in range(2, math.floor(x / 2)):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is both `isPrime` and `sumofPrimesX` are methods of the class `Problem10`.

Try the following:

```
import math

class Problem10:

    def sumOfPrimesX(self, number):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(0, number):
            if self.isPrime(i):
                sum += i
        return sum
    
    def isPrime(self, x):
        for n in range(0, math.floor(x/2)):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
        return True


pv = Problem10()
print(pv.sumOfPrimesX(input()))
```